# How to call C ++ method in C # using Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net-core, console, pinvoke

Am I doing it right? I have two projects in parallel, the first is code that was made in C ++ and the second project (Console made in AspNetCore v3.1) is the attempt to call the method that is in C ++ code.
I need to call the C ++ method "Decrypt" in the C # project. How do I do that?

C++ code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include "bascript.hpp"

extern "C"
int FAR PASCAL _export
Decript( const LPSTR name, const LPSTR passwordWithCript,
             LPSTR passwordWithoutCript, unsigned int sizeSpaceRetorn ) {

    LPSTR result = lpDecript( name, passwordWithCript);
    if ( sizeSpaceRetorn < strlen(result) )
       return 0;
       
    strcpy( passwordWithoutCript, result );
    delete result;
    return 1;
}
```

C#

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\MS\VS\TesteDLLCentura\TesteDLLCentura\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Sises.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "Decript")]
        private static extern string Decript(string name, string passwordWithCript, string passwordWithoutCript, uint sizeSpaceRetorn);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string retorno = Decript("<user>", "<cript_password>", "", 0);
            Console.WriteLine(retorno);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths? I.E. `[DllImport("Sises.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "Decript")]`

Comment: @Timothy G, With or without relative path it gives error.
(process 27840) exited with code -1073740940.

Comment: You're going to need to declare `StringBuilder passwordWithoutCript`, preinitialize it to a certain size, and pass that size in `sizeSpaceRetorn`. This will contain the actual result, ending in a NUL (0) character. The return type should be `int` not `string`

Answer (score -1):

You can return a pointer from native world (C/C++, etc.) as long as you use a .NET compatible memory allocator. On Windows, that would be the COM Allocator.

So here are 3 ways to return a string: Ansi, Unicode and BSTR (unicode). Note: you should avoid using Ansi on Windows.

C++ side:

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) void* DecryptA(const char* name, const char* password)
{
    char str[] = "hello ansi world";
    int size = (lstrlenA(str) + 1) * sizeof(char); // terminating zero

    // use .NET compatible allocator
    void* buffer = CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
    CopyMemory(buffer, str, size);
    return buffer;
}

extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) void* DecryptW(const wchar_t* name, const wchar_t* password)
{
    wchar_t str[] = L"hello unicode world";
    int size = (lstrlenW(str) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t); // terminating zero

    // use .NET compatible allocator
    void* buffer = CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
    CopyMemory(buffer, str, size);
    return buffer;
}

extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) BSTR DecryptBSTR(const wchar_t* name, const wchar_t* password)
{
    wchar_t str[] = L"hello BSTR world";

    // use .NET compatible allocator and COM coolness
    return SysAllocString(str);
}
```

C# side:

```
[DllImport("mydll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern string DecryptA(string name, string password);

[DllImport("mydll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern string DecryptW(string name, string password);

[DllImport("mydll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
private static extern string DecryptBSTR(string name, string password);

...

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DecryptA("name", "password"));
    Console.WriteLine(DecryptW("name", "password"));
    Console.WriteLine(DecryptBSTR("name", "password"));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Your C++ function does not return a `string` or equivalent. It returns an `int` result (success or failure), and the actual result goes in the `passwordWithoutCript` buffer.**

So you need to create the buffer and pass it in.

Because you are using `LPSTR` on the C++ side, you need `CharSet.Ansi`:

```cs
[DllImport(@"C:\MS\VS\TesteDLLCentura\TesteDLLCentura\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Sises.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Decript")]
private static extern int Decript(string name, string passwordWithCript, StringBuilder passwordWithoutCript, uint sizeSpaceRetorn);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(1000);  // or whatever size
    if(Decript("<user>", "<cript_password>", sb, sb.Length) == 1)
        Console.WriteLine(retorno);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Even making changes according to the code above, the application returns the following message: "This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated"

Comment: That message is a debugger message, telling you it will not execute certain types of code from Watch or Immediate windows. You will need to actually execute it. Are you getting an actual error?